# Postfix to Exchange Migrate Mailboxes

Tags: exchange, postfix, migration, mailbox

Has anyone migrated from postfix to Exchange and moved saved mails forward? I have been asked to move about 150 mailboxes, and I would rather avoid going down the Outlook/PST route if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Am sure on the postfix system you are running some sort of imap server, you can use [imapsync](http://ks.lamiral.info/imapsync/) to migrate the mail across to the exchange server while retaining the message flags.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Exchange? If it is small business server, you could use the POP3 connector to pull mail from the mailboxes. (Postfix by itself doesn't host mailboxes, you must be using something else alongside postfix to do this).

Obviously, I don't know your set up, but I'd recommend keeping postfix, as it [integrates quite nicely with Exchange/Active Directory](http://web.archive.org/web/20100728091538/http://www-personal.umich.edu/~malth/gaptuning/postfix/). Our company uses this set up, as postfix performs our virus and spam filtering (postfix, spamassassin, clamav, amavis), plus it means I don't have to expose port 25 of my exchange server to the world (which makes me very nervous!).

Edit: Just saw you have 150 mailboxes, so you won't be running SBS. An alternative would be to use [fetchmail](http://www.slipstick.com/exs/popconnect.asp) to do the job.

Comment: Problem is that customer insists on going to Exchange, and ditching postfix. It'll be latest version (it's a school). Just don't fancy bulk pulling mail via outlook, one box at a time.
You would *think* that with postfix being so popular, and MS wanting to steal their market share, that MS would write a mailbox puller.

Comment: postfix is set up as virtual mailboxes in /var/mail/vmail/user@domain